# Use Tor browser with selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, tor

Can Tor browser be used by Selenium?
I've tried

```cs
var profile = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile(@"..(TorBrowserPath)..\Tor Browser\Data\Browser");
var fFBinary = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxBinary(@"..(TorBrowserPath)..\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, profile);
```

And I'm Getting 
Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Here is your answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249820/failed-to-start-up-socket-within-45000/16854452

P.S. Upgrade Webdriver / Downgrade FF