# Selenium WebDriver 2.44 Firefox 33

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-webdriver, nuget

I'm using Firefox version 33.1.1 and Selenium WebDriver 2.44.  Selenium WebDriver was installed via Nuget using Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver.  Previously I've had no problems running tests.  I've started getting the following error on all my tests:

```
SetUp : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Looking at other sources of this error with different versions of Firefox and Selenium WebDriver, i.e. [Failed to start up socket within 45000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249820/failed-to-start-up-socket-within-45000), they all seem to centre on incompatibility between the Firefox version and the Selenium version.  However the release notes for Selenium 2.44 indicate compatibility with Firefox 33:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/dotnet/CHANGELOG

Has anybody else had this error with these versions of Firefox and Selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a version problem after all.  It turns out if you're updating Selenium via nuget, you need to be aware of which project the package manager console is pointing at.  I'd managed to update my main project to Selenium 2.44 but my test project was still on version 2.40.